# Is it possible to combine sequence and join for monadically created ConduitTs that have actions in the same monad?

Tags: haskell, conduit

In other words, is it possible to somehow combine something like `sequence` and `join` to have a function:

```
m (ConduitT a b m c) -> ConduitT a b m c
```

One immediate problem seems to be that `ConduitT` [doesn't have](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.1.2/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ConduitT) a `Foldable` instance, though there are [fold functions available](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.1.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Combinators.html). Though in any case, this may be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConduitT` is a monad transformer: it implements `lift :: m x -> ConduitT a b m x`.

```
join . lift :: m (ConduitT a b m c) -> ConduitT a b m c
```